# Angular, cannot access members of object in the array in custom pipes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Below is my custom pipe where I am unable to access the members of the customfilter array which is of type Item.

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Bus} from '/home/pavan/Desktop/Pavan/apstrtcAngular/src/app/Bus';
import { Item } from './Item';

@Pipe({
  name: 'busFilter'

})
export class BusFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: Bus[], customfilter: Item): Bus[] {
    if(!items || !customfilter)
    {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item: Bus)=> 
    this.applyFilter(item, customfilter));
  }

  applyFilter(bus:Bus, customfilter: Item):

    boolean{


        if( customfilter[0].item_id){
          if(typeof customfilter[0].item_id==='string'){
            if(typeof bus.bustype==='string')
            {
            if(customfilter[0].item_id===bus.bustype)
              {
                return false;
              }
          } }

        }

      return true;
    }

}
```

Below is my Item.ts and ng multiselect.

```
export class Item {
    /**
     * @type {number} id Unique numeric identifier.
     */
    item_id: string;
    item_text:string;
  }

<ng-multiselect-dropdown class="ngfilter"
              [placeholder]="'Select BusType'"
              [data]="BusTypes"
              [(ngModel)]="customfilter"
              [settings]="dropdownSettings"
              (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

I am unable to find the issue here, I cannot look at the value of item_id during debugging too. please help me to know where the issue is. Thank you.

Comment: `customfilter[0]`?? Is it an array or a class instance? Try `customfilter.item_id`

Comment: Also please show how are you using the pipe in the template

Comment: Thank you rajan, actually it was my mistake specifying wrong values in the if conditon. But i have an another problem. If there are more  than two values in the customFilter array, I am not able to iterate the json multiple times. Please let me know how can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: customfilter is array of type item with two attribute (item_id, item_text)

Comment: If its an array then you should be able to iterate, please show the complete code for your doubts.. Please show the array and how/where are you iterating

Comment: If there are multiple objects in customFilter(basically more than one item_text), i want to search the item_text in the json multiple times and output the results

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Bus} from '/home/pavan/Desktop/Pavan/apstrtcAngular/src/app/Bus';
import { Item } from './Item';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Pipe({
  name: 'busFilter'
})
  export class BusFilterPipe implements PipeTransform 
  {

        transform(items: Bus[], customfilter: Item[]): Bus[] {
          let ResultSet: Bus[] = [];
          if (!items || !customfilter) {
            return items;
          }
          else if (customfilter.length == 0) {
            return items;
          }
          else{
          for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < customfilter.length; j++) {
              if (customfilter[j].item_text === items[i].bustype) {
                ResultSet.push(items[i]);
                console.log("Result Set =" + ResultSet);
              }
            }
          }
          return ResultSet;
        }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and my understanding of your code written in the pipe, modify your  pipe like this (please read through the comments in the code):

```
transform(items: Bus[], customfilter: Item[]): Bus[] {

    if(!items || !customfilter)
    {
      return items;
    }

    // making custom filter an Array if it isn't already
    customFilter = customFilter instanceof Array ? customFilter : [customFilter];

    // you seem to ignore the custom filters which don't have item_id
    customFilter = customFilter.filter((eachCustom) => eachCustom.item_id);

    // create an array of new items which satisfy your criteria
    return items.reduce((acc, eachBus) => {
        // if bus's bustype is not string then no need to filter
        if (typeof eachBus.bustype != 'string') {
            acc.push(eachBus)
        }
        else {
            // if the bustype is a string
            // then you have to see if this bus's bustype matches any of the custom filters and it's id type
            // if not found then that bus should be present in the final bus list
            let filterFound = customFilter.findIndex((eachFilter) => {
                return (typeof eachFilter.item_id === 'string') && (typeof eachBus.bustype === 'string') && (eachFilter.item_id === eachBus.bustype);
            });

            if (filterFound === -1) {
                // this bus is not found in the filter
                acc.push(eachBus)
            }
        }
        return acc;

    }, [])

}
```

**Below is a script in javascript to verify the result**

```js
function transform(items, customfilter) {

    if(!items || !customfilter)
    {
      return items;
    }

    // making custom filter an Array if it isn't already
    customFilter = customFilter instanceof Array ? customFilter : [customFilter];

    // you seem to ignore the custom filters which don't have item_id
    customFilter = customFilter.filter((eachCustom) => eachCustom.item_id);

    // create an array of new items which satisfy your criteria
    return items.reduce((acc, eachBus) => {
        // if bus's bustype is not string then no need to filter
        if (typeof eachBus.bustype != 'string') {
            acc.push(eachBus)
        }
        else {
            // if the bustype is a string
            // then you have to see if this bus's bustype matches any of the custom filters and it's id type
            // if not found then that bus should be present in the final bus list
            let filterFound = customFilter.findIndex((eachFilter) => {
                return (typeof eachFilter.item_id === 'string') && (typeof eachBus.bustype === 'string') && (eachFilter.item_id === eachBus.bustype);
            });

            if (filterFound === -1) {
                // this bus is not found in the filter
                acc.push(eachBus)
            }
        }
        return acc;

    }, [])

}


let buses = [{bustype: 1}, {bustype: "volvo-ac"}, {bustype: "volvo-non-ac"}, {bustype: "non-volvo-ac"}, {bustype: "non-volvo-non-ac"}]
let customFilter = [{item_id: "volvo-ac"}, {item_id: "non-volvo-ac"}]
console.log(transform(buses, customFilter))
// expected output won't contain the buses present in the filter
```

Comment: Hello Ashish, the above is only working when the length of customfilter is 1. I just need a way to filter using an array of customfilter whose length is more than 1. Thank you

Comment: @PavanSista: It works for me as far as I have understood your requirement, see the executable code, it has customFilter containing filters more than one.

Comment: I was able to execute the code, but it only works for first object of the array customFilter, there is no output for the second object of the array.

Comment: @PavanSista: Analyze the code, first check if it fits your requirements, you may have some other keys than the one I am using, Or some other conditions, see why the executable script in the answer is able to filter out from an array of custom filters and why your custom filter isn't working.

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks for helping me out.